# Parse CNN Fear and Greed

Tags: python, trading

After multiple hours of googeling and trying the following code used to work to get the fear and greed index out of the cnn website. I used this code to sent it to me via Mail together with other numbers so that I can read it before market open.

Now CNN changed their website and I can't get the value any longer. I tried multiple things but I can't get the value, I just get the javascript code.

Could somebody give me a hint what I can do to get the value out of the website? I also tried selenium but I get the same, not the value but the javascript variable.

```
import datetime
import os.path
import re
import tempfile
import typing
import pytz
import requests
import requests_cache

requests_cache.install_cache(
    cache_name=os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "cnn_cache"),
    expire_after=datetime.timedelta(minutes=1),
)

URL = "https://money.cnn.com/data/fear-and-greed/"
REGEXP = re.compile(
    """
    Greed\ Now:\ (?P<value>\d+)                       # the index value, [0-100].
    \s
    \((?P<description>.*?)\)                          # e.g. "Neutral", non-greedy.
    .*                                                # ignore in-between HTML code.
    Last\ updated\ (?P<last_update>.*?(?:am|pm))  # e.g. "Nov 27 at 5:00pm"
""",
    re.VERBOSE,
)

class FearGreedIndex(typing.NamedTuple):
    value: int
    description: str
    last_update: datetime.datetime

class Fetcher:
    def __call__(self) -> str:
        r = requests.get(URL)

        print(r.text)
        return r.text


def _parse_date(d: str) -> datetime.datetime:
    eastern = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")
    now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=eastern)
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%b %d at %I:%M%p").replace(year=now.year)
    date = date.replace(tzinfo=eastern)
    return date


def get(fetcher=None) -> FearGreedIndex:
    if fetcher is None:
        fetcher = Fetcher()

    match = re.search(REGEXP, fetcher())
    if match:
        group = match.group
        return FearGreedIndex(
            int(group("value")),
            group("description"),
            _parse_date(group("last_update")),
        )
    raise ValueError("couldn't parse {}".format(URL))


def get_current_fear_and_freed_value():
    results = get()
    value = results.value
    description = results.description
    date = results.last_update.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    return date, value, description
```

Comment: Hi Axel, welcome to Stack Overflow. Inspecting the code of the webpage, it looks like the images are served by an API. https://production.dataviz.cnn.io/index/fearandgreed/graphdata/2022-04-24 . It looks you can get an observation for each data set by changing the date at the end of that URL. Even better, you can get what looks like the full set of data here: https://production.dataviz.cnn.io/index/fearandgreed/graphdata

Answer (score 0):

The code you show in your question is from [an older version](https://github.com/vterron/fear-and-greed/blob/v.11/src/fear_and_greed/cnn.py) of package [`fear-and-greed`](https://pypi.org/project/fear-and-greed/). This library now supports the endpoint [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71998247/parse-cnn-fear-and-greed#comment127221972_71998247) by Col Bates above:

```
>>> import fear_and_greed
>>> fear_and_greed.get()
FearGreedIndex(value=11.5224, description='extreme fear', last_update=datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 20, 22, 22, 16, 186000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))
```